# Why are Twisted's DeferredFilesystemLocks not safe for concurrent use?

Tags: python, twisted, filelock

In the [Twisted API for DeferredFilesystemLock](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.DeferredFilesystemLock.html), it is stated that `deferUntilLocked` is not safe for concurrent use.

I would like to understand in what way it is unsafe and what makes it unsafe, in order to ensure that I don't misuse the file locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably the method is actually quite safe for concurrent use.  If you read [the first four lines of the implementation](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.1.0/twisted/internet/defer.py#L1541) then it's clear that an attempt at concurrent use will immediately raise `AlreadyTryingToLockError`.

Perhaps the warning is meant to tell you that you'll get an exception rather than useful locking behavior, though.

The implementation of that exception should provide a hint about why concurrent use isn't allowed.  `DeferredFilesystemLock` uses some instance attributes, starting with `_tryLockCall`, to keep track of progress in the attempt to acquire the lock.  If concurrent attempts were allowed, they would each trample over the use of this attribute (and others) by each other.

This could be enhanced with relative ease.  All that would be necessary is to keep the state associated with the lock attempt on a new object allocated per-attempt (instead of on the `DeferredFilesystemLock` instance).  [Or, `DeferredLock` could help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990697/python-twisteds-deferredlock/18993262#18993262)

Answer (score 1):

The first and most obvious thing that comes to mind is that in concurrent situations you're never guaranteed to acquire the lock (if another thread never releases it), so you may `defer` forever. You could avoid this by simply passing the optional `timeout` to `deferUntilLocked`.

Other things to consider that may make this unsuitable for concurrent use:

- Starvation: What if multiple threads are continually waiting to acquire the same lock - are they treated fairly, or will one thread spend longer waiting than others? Are threads guaranteed to eventually acquire the lock?
- Deadlocks: If you're acquiring multiple locks at a time, and multiple threads are doing this, you may get into a situation where you have two threads both waiting on a resource that the other one holds.
- Are you sure that acquired locks are always released? What if one thread acquires a lock and crashes without releasing it?

It looks to me like Twisted's implementation is fairly simple and probably doesn't take into account many of these things. Their "not safe" comment is a "there be dragons here" - you may/will get difficult to troubleshoot concurrent bugs or issues if you try to use this in a concurrent application.

Comment: Although keep in mind that all (except one) Twisted APIs are *explicitly* not thread-safe.  None of the "what if two threads ..." scenarios are good explanations for the warning because it is implicit that you may not use the API in two threads.